# How to remove last gap grid

Tags: css, material-ui, css-grid

How should I make a layout with 5 boxes ? So far, this is all I can do. But the problem is that the last item of the grid still has a gap below it.
I only able to provide styled component for Container.

```css
const Container = styled('div')`
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 3fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 5fr 0.75fr 1fr;
  gap: 10px;
  & > div {
    min-height: 20px;
  }
  & > .container-live-call {
    grid-column: 1 / span 3;
    background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.color.secondary.$100};
  }
  & > .container-live-call-map {
    grid-row: 2 / span 3;
    background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.color.secondary.$100};
  }
  & > .container-live-call-info {
    grid-row: 2 / span 3;
    background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.color.secondary.$100};
  }
  & > .container-live-call-volume {
    grid-column: 3;
    background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.color.secondary.$100};
  }
  & > .container-live-call-voice {
    grid-column: 3;
    background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.color.secondary.$100};
  }
`;
```

```
      <Container>
        <div className="container-live-call"></div>
        <div className="container-live-call-map"></div>
        <div className="container-live-call-info"></div>
        <div className="container-live-call-volume"></div>
        <div className="container-live-call-voice">
          <button onClick={() => setOpen(false)}>Click me to close</button>
        </div>
      </Container>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.container-live-call-map` and `.container-live-call-info` rules are adding an additional row to 4 total rows (instead of 3 as defined in `grid-template-rows`) because they are starting at row 2 and spanning 3 rows. If you change them to:

```
.container  > .container-live-call-map {
    grid-row: 2 / span 2;
}
.container  > .container-live-call-info {
    grid-row: 2 / span 2;
}
```

This should get rid of that extra row/gap below the last item of the grid.